# Using the current version of selenium, how do I mock an api response in csharp using the new selenium network interception features?

Tags: api, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The following code snippet is in java. I want to recreate the an equivalent in csharp. The viewAllTodos function uses the new features of selenium network interception to intercept an api response, modify the contents and then forward it on the ui. It appears that the csharp bindings of selenium is being changed frequently so existing examples are now dysfunctional
` @Test
public void viewAllTodos() throws JsonProcessingException {

```
    WebDriver driver = PageStateHelpers.getWebDriverForApplication();

    List<TodoItem> items = new ArrayList<>();//The content that would be used to replace the intercepted api response
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
        items.add(TodoItem.builder().id(i+1).caption("Todo Item "+i).isDone(i>10).build());//Replacement api Response being formed
    }

    String body = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(items);

    NetworkInterceptor interceptor = new NetworkInterceptor(driver,   //NetworkInterceptor is created
            Route.matching(req->req.getUri().contains("/api/todo")).to( //The interceptor will intercept any url with /api/dodo
                    ()-> req-> new HttpResponse() //It will replace it with a the new response being created
                            .setStatus(200)
                            .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8")
                            .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                            .setContent(utf8String(body)) // It will set the content of the response with some modified information
            )
    );
    driver.get("http://localhost:3000");
```

}
`

I've searched the web for a solution to no avail. The few examples that come close were in the beta stage or alpha stage and so are no longer working

Comment: I've searched for Javascript too, still nothing. I wonder if it can be done...